# php curl send custom header

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

i am trying to send custom header to the same file (using curl in php)

this is the file (test.php) :

```
   @session_start();

   @session_unset(($_SESSION['token']));

   if(empty($_SESSION['token'])){

      $_SESSION['token'] = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));
   }

   $token = $_SESSION['token'];

   $uri = 'http://localhost/test.php'; // the samw file
   $ch = curl_init($uri);
   curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
   CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER  => array('X-Simple-Protection: '.$token.''),
   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  =>true,
   CURLOPT_VERBOSE  => 1));
   $out = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);


   if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_SIMPLE_PROTECTION'] == $token){ 

       echo "token : ".token;
   }else{
       echo "error";  
   }
```

When I run the file I get the following error :

> Notice: Undefined index:     HTTP_X_SIMPLE_PROTECTION in
>   C:\Users\me\Desktop\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 24    error

I try to send to the file itself , Is this possible?

Comment: `print_r($_SERVER);` but this file will just endlessly call itself.

Comment: @AbraCadaver What should I do please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)